# CakePHP 3.0 hasOne association update by id

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have `ModelA`, which "hasOne" `ModelB`.

I already have a row in DB in the `ModelB` table with ID 1, but `modelA_id` is set to `NULL`. Now I want to add a row into the `ModelA` table and I want it to be associated to the row in `ModelB` with ID 1.

I tried doing:

```
$newA = $modelATable->newEntity(["modelB_id" => 1]);
$modelATable->save($newA);
```

which indeed does create a new row in the `ModelA` table, but the `modelA_id` field in `ModelB` table is not updated.

What does work is this, for example:

```
$newA = $modelATable->newEntity(["modelB" => ["id" => 1, "modelA_id" => $newId]]);
$modelATable->save($newA);
```

but this is cumbersome and not really what I want (can't know modelA_id in advance -> I would just have to update the `modelA_id` field after the new row has been added)

Associations are properly set and `'modelB_id' = true` in `$_accessible` in the Entity class of `ModelA`.

Is this not possible or am I not understanding something right or is this just a mistake on my part somewhere? No (validation) errors are thrown when first piece of code is used, which leads me to believe that the Marshaller does not do anything with `modelB_id`, it just ends up being a redundant field.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Kinda unrelated, but does saving without any properties being set for the main entity really work? I kinda doubt that.

Comment: No, it's just an example :). There are other properties being set, but the main point is about these fields specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `modelB_id` field on `ModelA` doesn't make any sense in a `hasOne` association, as the other table has the foreign key, which is `modelA_id`, so that's why the marshaller ignores it, that is the expected behavior.

Your second variant is the correct one, however there is no need to define the foreign key, all you need to pass is the primary key, the foreign key field will be updated automatically in case the associations are set up properly, ie this is all that should be necessary for the association:

```
'modelB' => [
    'id' => 1
]
```

See also

- **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-hasone-associations**
- **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#associated-form-inputs**